# Javascript For-loop in onChange event

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-select, onchange

I'm trying to create a select option bar that when onChange event is triggered, it returns the index of the selected file. For the first few selections, I get the correct number for the location of its index. However, after the third selection, the index being returned becomes 1 everytime I make a selection on the selection bar. Is there a way to fix this?

```
    function handleUtilities(selection){
        var index = selection.selectedIndex;
        var selected = selection.options[index].value;

        accountIndex = getOneUtility(data, selected);
    }

    function getOneUtility(array, utility){
        var start = [];
        var end = [];
        var cost = [];
        var usage = [];
        var row = 0;
        utility = utility.substring(0, utility.indexOf(")")+1);

        for(row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
            data = array[row][0];

            if(data.indexOf(utility) != -1){
                row += 3;
                break;
            }
        }

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: can you post what `data` equals?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are overwriting `data` in your for loop and the update to `data` doesn't impact functionality until the third run.

I suggest changing `data = array[row][0];` to `var data = array[row][0];` based on the supplied information.